# VS2010 web application won't build after adding web service reference

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a web application project being developed in VS2010 targetting Framework 4.0. I need to add a reference to a web service. On the same machine that I am developing on, I created a new project - set the target framework as 3.5 - and selected Web Service Application - and created a Web Service with the default HelloWorld method. I then changed the targed Framework to 4.0 and published this Web Service to a local server - http://mylocalserver/myWebService/Service1.asmx and, if I put that in a browser it all works fine - the Hello World method is displayed and, if you click it, it executes okay and displays "Hello World".

I then added a Service Reference to my web application project - clicked Advanced and added a Web Service reference. During this process the web service was found and it reported that the Hello World method was available. So, add the web refernce and in the solution I can see under Web References - myWebService - Reference.map - Reference.cs - Service1.disco - Service1.wsdl

Then, if I try to build the web application project the build fails. It says 'Error 48  Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Development\EVProject\EVProject\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

If I remove the reference to the web service - it all builds okay and works fine. If I put the reference to the Hello World web service back in -it won't build. Take it out it builds and works fine.

Any idea why adding the web reference is preventing it from building? Thanks for any help.

Edit: A bit more info ...

A bit more info. On the same development machine I have a Web Site Project. I just added the same web reference to that project and called the web service from it. It builds fine - and calls the web service correctly.

So, two applications on the same development machine.

Both VS2010 - both targetting Framework 4.0

One is a Web Site Project

The other is a Web Application Project

If I add the same web reference to both projects, the Web Application will not build - the Web Site project builds fine and calls the web service correctly. So, who won't the Web Application Project build?

Comment: Additional info removed and added to original question.

Comment: Is it related to AjaxTookKit. As far as I know, different version go with different version of AjaxTookKit. It might work with one but not the other, is this the case?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. When you say 'is it related to Ajax Toolkit?' .... is what related to Ajax Toolkit? The web application project references Ajax Toolkit but builds and works perfectly - until I add a reference to the web service. At which point the web application will not build saying it could not load the Ajax Assembly. Why would doing something as innocent as adding a reference to a web service mean that, suddenly, the Ajax Toolkit dll won't load?

Comment: I mean is it Ajax related? It looks like this could be a conflict with Ajax Library you are using. I can not entirely get into it but are the version of both the application are same? As you said you were using 4.0 and 3.5. Ajax might  be compatible with one but not both. Try changing the .NET framework to the one which works and see.

Comment: The web service was created for 3.5 and changed to 4.0.

The web application project is Framework 4.0

The ajax toolkit dll is the latest one - I can't see why adding a reference to a web service that has the typical Hello World method should stop the web application building. I think the fact that it can't load the ajax toolkit dll may be a red herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem: my project didn't build after adding a web reference. I was able to build it disabling 'Generate serialization assembly' option from my project properties build tab.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. In the meantime I gave up and created a WCF service (or whatever the latest thing is called - can't keep up with all the acronyms). Which works fine but is a lot more tricky to get working that a web service.

Comment: I had a different assembly "not load" after adding the Web Reference (seems to throw the error on the first assembly it finds), but setting "Generate serialization assembly" from "Auto" to "Off" worked for me as well.